# I computed ARMA equation from R manually but never got the same result with predict() or forecast() provided by R

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I've got a little problem here. I've been doing analysis with time series data using ARMA, and it always turns out that the parameters I get from R didn't fit to my computation when I do it manually.

To make it general, here I put my analysis using 'lh' dataset:

```
> #Given 'lh' dataset which provided me a ts dataset with 48 periods of time
> lh
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 48 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.2 2.1 1.5 2.3 2.3 2.5 2.0 1.9 1.7 2.2 1.8 3.2 3.2 2.7 2.2 2.2 1.9
[21] 1.9 1.8 2.7 3.0 2.3 2.0 2.0 2.9 2.9 2.7 2.7 2.3 2.6 2.4 1.8 1.7 1.5 1.4 2.1 3.3
[41] 3.5 3.5 3.1 2.6 2.1 3.4 3.0 2.9
> 
> #I divided the dataset into training and testing
> lh.train <- lh[1:45] #training data is from period 1 to 45
> lh.test <- lh[46:48] #testing data is from period 46 to 48
> 
> #Then I applied ARMA(1,1) to training dataset
> fit <- arima(lh.train, order = c(1,0,1))
> fit #from this output, I'd get the equation Yt = 2.3467 + 0.4507Yt-1 + et - 0.2533et-1

Call:
arima(x = lh.train, order = c(1, 0, 1))

Coefficients:
         ar1     ma1  intercept
      0.4507  0.2533     2.3467
s.e.  0.1701  0.1557     0.1370

sigma^2 estimated as 0.1696:  log likelihood = -24.18,  aic = 56.37
> 
> #I did forecast to 3 periods of time, which are period 46, 47, and 48 from the original dataset
> lh.forecast <- predict(fit, n.ahead=3)
> 
> #Then, I want to compare the prediction using R and computed manually
> #let's say to period of 46
> lh.forecast$pred[1] #it will give me prediction of period 46
[1] 2.151328
```

As you can see, that from my R output the prediction to period 46 is 2.151328. From `fit` I get the equation like Yt = 2.3467 + 0.4507Yt-1 + et - 0.2533et-1. But when I calculated it manually, using et-1 and Yt-1 from here:

```
> fit$residuals[45] #et-1
[1] -0.3323993
> lh.train[45] #Yt-1
[1] 2.1
```

my calculation wasn't correct. I got prediction to period-46: 3.349711, which is not equal to the R code prediction.

Why was my prediction not correct? Did I do something wrong? Is it because of my equation? Did I misinterpreted? Cause it's not the only time that this matter happened. Every time I did analysis with ARIMA, it always turned like this. And since my colleagues want to know the real equation, I'm afraid what I've done was wrong. Please help me :(

Comment: The "intercept" is actually the mean. See https://otexts.org/fpp2/arima-r.html#understanding-constants-in-r

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the coefficient that is called "intercept" would be more accurately identified as the "mean".

```
as.numeric(fit$coef)[3]+as.numeric(fit$coef)[1]*(lh[45]-as.numeric(fit$coef)[3])+as.numeric(fit$coef)[2]*fit$residuals[45]

[1] 2.151328
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html#understanding-constants-in-r):

> By default, the Arima() function sets c=μ=0 when d > 0 and provides an estimate of μ when d = 0.

Since this model has `d = 0`, the constant is the mean of `yt`. Thus, the correct equation is:

`2.3467 + (2.1 - 2.3467) * 0.4507 + 0.2533 * -0.3323993`